# Two-way binding in Vue.js with prop.sync and watcher

Tags: javascript, vue.js, two-way-binding

I'm having trouble understanding the two-way binding between a parent and child component. So far, what I've read seems to recommend using prop.sync in conjunction with watching the prop. E.g:

Parent:

```
<child-component :childProp.sync="parentData"></child-component>
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <input v-model="childData" @input="$emit('update:childProp', childData);"></input>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['childProp'],
    data() {
      childData: childProp
    },
    watch: {
      childProp(newValue) {
        this.childData = newValue;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

My problem with this is, wouldn't this create some sort of redundancy when either the parentData or the childData is updated?
The flow would be thus (for parentData changed):

1. parentData changes ->
2. triggers watch ->
3. childData changes ->
4. triggers .sync ->
5. parentData updated.

I'm assuming the cycle stops at step #5 because the updated value of the parentData is the same as the old value, so parentData doesn't really change, hence step #2 watcher is not triggered.

My problem with this is, if my reasoning is right, there will be some sort of redundancy in that changes to the parentData will go to the child and reflect back to itself, and vice versa. The reflection is the redundancy. Am I right so far? Or is my understanding of this completely off?

If I'm wrong, please help me understand where I went wrong. But if I'm right, then is there another way to achieve two-way binding without this redundancy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you can simplify a child component code like this:

```html
<template>
  <input :value="childProp" @input="$emit('update:childProp', $event);"></input>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['childProp']
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work with a custom input component that doesn't accept a :value prop though. For example, I'm using bootstrap-vue, so I can't use ```<b-form-input :value="childProp"></b-form-input>``` because the component simply doesn't accept that as a prop.

Comment: `b-form-input` uses `v-model` that means under the hood it uses `:value` and `@input`

Comment: Thanks @Anatoly. How come the watcher is no longer necessary? Will this simplified child component still update if the ```parentData``` changes?

Comment: A watcher is needed if you wish to transform any parent data into a child data. In this case you don't need any intermediate child props.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm pretty new to Vue, so might be missing something important.

Also, all the below is based on working with Vue 2.

### 1. I experienced the opposite effect - changing the value in the child affects the template, but doesn't trigger parent's watchers

In my real-life case, the parent handles server calls for several child components handling settings UI. When the parent changes the props (e.g. after fetching current settings from the server), the child's state should change with no other effects. But when the child changes the prop (e.g. on user interaction), the parent should trigger a request to the server to update the relevant setting.

### 2. My solution

This is a variant on Vue's [v-model for custom components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components#Using-v-model-on-Components).

Instead of using the `.sync` modifier, child components have a **value** prop and an **internalValue** data property for each should-be-synced prop.

All changes to **internalValue** aren't applied directly, but through a `changeInternalValue` function, which takes a `shouldEmit` argument. `shouldEmit` is true for child changes and false for parent changes (e.g. from the watcher of **value**).

Something like this:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
    props: ['isEnabled'],      
    data: {
         isEnabledInternal: this.isEnabled,
    },
    watch: {
        isEnabled: {
            handler: function(newVal) {
                this.changeInternalIsEnabled(newVal, false);
            },
            immediate: true,
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onToggle: function(newVal) { // triggered from component's template on user interaction
            this.changeInternalIsEnabled(newVal, true);
        },
        changeInternalIsEnabled: function(newVal) {            
            if (newVal !== this.isEnabledInternal) {
                this.isEnabledInternal = newVal;
                if (shouldEmit) {
                    this.$emit('my-component-changed', this.isEnabledInternal);
                }                
            }
        },
    },
});
```

The parent component listens on `my-component-changed` event and changes `isEnabled` according to the event's value (via `<my-component @my-component-changed="setEnabledAndDoStuff">` in its template). This will trigger the child's watcher, but without emitting the event again.